# Example of custom model field extending ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, djangoappengine

Can someone give me an example of extending a ForeignKey model field? I tried like this:

```
class ForeignKeyField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ForeignKeyField, self).__init__(Chain.objects.all(), *args, **kwargs)
    def clean(self, value):
        return Chain.objects.get(pk=value)      

class CustomForeignKey(models.ForeignKey):
    description = "key from ndb"
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomForeignKey, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def db_type(self, connection):
        return "ndb"

    def to_python(self, value):
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        from google.appengine.api.datastore_types import Key

        if isinstance(value, Key) is True:
            return value.id()
        if value is None:
            return
        return value

    def get_db_prep_save(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        save_value = ndb.Key(API_Chain, value.id).to_old_key()
        return save_value

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return models.Field.formfield(self,ForeignKeyField, **kwargs)
```

I don't know why but if i use `__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase` the to_python gets called with None values and it says that foreign key cannot be null. If I inherit from models.Field it works but not as a foreign Key.
I would like to see how one can extend the functionality of models.ForeignKey. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need SubfieldBase? It does some magic behind the scenes so that the field has a descriptor that calls to_python. ForeignKey has different kind of descriptor. I guess ForeignKey descriptor is overridden by the subfieldbase descriptor. In other words, they arenot compatible.

Comment: Can I make them compatible? Or can i force it to override this?